# Can I use emacs to copy a line from other window to my current one?

Tags: emacs, diff

Suppose I have to code files which are supposed to be similar but has some minor changes. For example, file `foo`:

```
int a,b,c
a=1
b=2
c=3
```

and file `bar`

```
int a,b,c
a=1
b=2
c=4
```

I know that I'm better of placing the changes in a properties file but, It is harder to follow that way. Now, suppose that I need to change the files to be (`foo`) in this example

```
int a,b,c,d
a=1
b=2
c=3
d=a+b+c
```

After I've changed one file, I want to compare the two files, and apply the desired changes to my files. Currently, what I'm doing is open two windows and compare them (`M-x compare-windows`). When I encounter a line that I want to change, I copy it from `foo` to `bar` (adding to kill ring etc.) I'm quite certain there is a better way to do it. Do you know it?

Answer (score 2):

Seems you are looking for <kbd>M-x</kbd> ediff-buffers <kbd>RET</kbd>, resp. <kbd>M-x</kbd> ediff-buffers3 <kbd>RET</kbd>

Comment: From what I gather, <kbd>M-x </kbd>ediff-buffers <kbd>RET</kbd>, only highlight the differences between the buffers, they don't allow me to accept or reject a change...